# Can't find airflow to gcp hook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, package, airflow

after installing the gcp package to my airflow(1.10.9) set-up, i tried to call on the GSheetHook 
https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/airflow/providers/google/suite/hooks/sheets/index.html

but i get an error No module named 'airflow.providers'.
looking into the installed python packages for airflow, i do not find the providers package.

[image: python packages]

is the gcp airflow packagge working or am i missingg a step before i am able to use it?

EDIT: I have installed the gcp  package using the pip installer: pip install apache-airflow[gcp]
and here's the list of the installed packages

[image]

Comment: How did you install the GCP package to Airflow? Take note that the documentation you're using is for Airflow 1.10.10, the 1.10.9 is a bit different: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.9/_api/airflow/contrib/hooks/index.html

Comment: Can you show how you are installing the packages, importing them and which version of the libraries are you using?

Comment: i have edited the post to answer your questions

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are trying to do?

Comment: i am trying to feed some data into a google spreadsheet and i need to use the GSheetHook to do that, it is installed through thr gcp package

Comment: I thik 'providers' module is only available in current `master` branch onwards - https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/airflow/providers. I just installed fresh 'pip install apache-airflow[gcp]' > v1.10.10 and `providers` package still missing. @CEH can you pls. share how you installed Airflow (which version) with `providers` package to be able to successfully import GSheetHook. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The "providers" package is only available in Airflow Master. We plan to release each provider as a separate packages as "backport packages", most likely in a week or two from today.

PR to do that: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/8807

You should be checking https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.9/ for Airflow 1.10.9 docs. You are looking at the docs for "latest" which is for Master.

Answer (score 1):

It looks backport packages (providers) can now be installed in v1.10* using with following pip command `$pip install apache-airflow-backport-providers-PACKAGE-NAME`